# What is this SRIB_DCS logging in Android logcat and how do I stop it?

Tags: android

When I run my android app on Android v5 I my logcat is flooded with the following message which makes it very difficult to debug things. Anytime something on the screen changes it logs. So, for example, if I have a progress spinner on screen I get thousands of log lines.

Does anyone know what is logging this and how I can disable it or its logging?

```
11-10 14:08:13.580  27909-27909/com.example.myapp D/SRIB_DCS﹕ Setting dcs flag to enable shadow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my local dev build to use maven rather than letting IDEA do it and this went away.